# Can I remove the "legacy" items (script templates, vb6 event system) entries from the database (and config files) by running any installer/tool?

Tags: 2013, installation, legacy-pack

We upgraded from Tridion 2011 SP1 to Tridion 2013. The process was pretty straight forward, A clean install of 2013 using the installer and a Database Upgrade using the scripts. I wasn't involved in the upgrade task.

What I do see know is that in such database there are still referneces to "legacy" items such as scripting templates and every time I try to get a list of Building Blocks (via Template Builder, Core Service, etc...) I get the following error:

[image: Legacy Items Error]

The good thing is that it clearly states that the legacy pack is missing and there's references 'somewhere' to legacy items. So here is what I need to know:

1. What does the legacy pack install? Is it just dlls? COM+ is out of the question here and the infra guys won't allow that in the server (one of the reasons for the upgrade was to remove all the "old" dependencies)
2. Could I remove the references to the legacy items from the database/system instead? How?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5):

COM+ not allowed? Then you shall not run SDL Tridion! The Licencing module is still COM+ even in Tridion 2013 SP1...

Legacy pack contains the TDSE COM+ application as well as DLLs, configuration entries and database items (you already have the database items in your database hence the problem because you do not have the corresponding DLLs and configuration entries).

You can try to remove ALL legacy items from the database before migrating the database to the new version. If you forget one you will end up in the same scenario though so in your case I would advise to install the legacy pack (as is SDL's own recommendation when performing upgrades).

Comment: Interesting... somewhere I read/heard that SDL Tridion 2013 didn't require the COM+ anymore.

Comment: Depends on the definition of "Tridion" I guess. Some components still us COM+ just like Microsoft Office

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to just walk over the items and delete them. You may try to script it. It's a lot of work, but this is the only "right" way. Otherwise you may write a SQL query which will change template type of the legacy stuff to C# or DreamWeaver, for example. You will still be able to open and inspect them, but not use and in the end you will still have to delete it.